# How do I get this regular expression to match my desired input

Tags: java, regex

I tried to match the "MY WEIGHT" from the following string. I'm using Java's String class to do the regex match:

```
String line = "MY WEIGHT:200";
String s = "^(MY WEIGHT).";
line.matches(s);
```

But it always returns false. Then I tried `s="MY WEIGHT"` but it doesn't work either. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two don't match: `.` matches a *single* character but `line` has 4 characters after `"MY WEIGHT"` - did you mean `.*` (at least 0 characters) or `.+` (at least 1 character)?

Comment: That's correct. There should be `.*`. Does the star `*` after the dot `.` mean matching the previous element zero or more times?

Comment: @tonga No, it simply means 0 or more arbitrary characters (`.*` essentially matches anything).

Comment: That's why it confuses me. From regular expression wiki, it says star `*` matches the preceding element zero or more times. But when star is used with dot `.`, it changes its meaning.

Comment: @tonga Yes, think of it as "what precedes 0 or more times". So `.*` means `.` 0 or more times, but not all of those `.`s need to be the *same* character.

Comment: That is correct. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

String's `.match` has to match the *entire* string with the regular expression rather than just a substring.  This is why `s="MY WEIGHT"` does not work either.

String s = "^(MY WEIGHT).*";

will match.  If you are more specific about your needs, it will be easier to construct a more specific regular expression.